# Positioning multiple backgrounds in css3

Tags: css, background, background-image

I've got following setup

```
background-image: url(image1.png) , url(image2.png);
```

Idea is that `image1.png` repeats everywhere whereas `image2.png` should only start 200px from pages top and only `repeat-x`. I know you can position background like:

```
background-position: top left, left bot etc...
```

But how do I position it 200px from top of the page? and make it `repeat-x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the shorthand for background:

```
{background: url(image1.png) repeat, url(image2.png) 0 200px repeat-x;}
```

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/